# Logic behind Java shift operations implementation

Tags: java, python, c#, bit-manipulation, shift

According to Section 15.19 of the JLS:

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the five
>   lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift
>   distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a
>   bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f
>   (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the
>   range 0 to 31, inclusive.
>
> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is long, then only the
>   six lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift
>   distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a
>   bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x3f
>   (0b111111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in
>   the range 0 to 63, inclusive.

The same thing we can find in C#. In Python it will be 6 bits instead of 5, but the logic remains the same.

What the reasoning behind it? For me it would be more naturally to have the following:

```
x << 32 = 0
```

instead of

```
x << 32 = x
```

Moreover we will never get 0 using shift operation for negative ints.

Comment: Aren't you talking about "shifting" vs "rotation"?

Answer (score 0):

From book "Java Puzzlers: Traps, Pitfalls and Corner Cases" by Joshua Bloch and Neal Gafter:

> Language designers should perhaps consider restricting shift distances to the range from 0 to the type size in bits and changing the semantics of shifting a value by the type size to return 0. Although this would avoid the confusion …, it could have negative performance consequences; Java's semantics for the shift operators are those of the shift instructions on many processors.

Comment: Thank you! Could you be more specific about second part of the quote? What kind of shift restriction do we have on CPU? And why we have it? I will appreciate for any example!

Comment: I am no expert in CPU machine code but I image the following:
With the current Java semantics of the shift operators, when the Java bytecode is being translated to assembler/machine code, the shift operation is simple passed without any modifications, e.g. as a single CPU operation. If the semantics was different, multiple CPU operations would have to be produced to make the resulting machine code match the Java language specification.

Comment: It perfectly make sense, but I’m wondering exactly about reasoning behind CPU logic.

Comment: I see. I suggest that you post a separate question, probably on a different site (https://stackexchange.com/sites).